# Update music files on Nokia E71 keep getting disconnected via USB 

Tags: windows, nokia-e-series

Previously, I could update my music files on my [Nokia E71](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_E71) using [Ovi Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovi_(Nokia)#Ovi_Player).

Now whenever I plug in my E71 I choose PC suite. I go to Ovi Player in my laptop, and I select the mobile phone section, and I press the connect button and my phone is automatically disconnected via USB.

The alternative is to choose media transfer or media player. The same thing happens. And the connecting screen at Ovi Player is like hanged.

I have previously transferred songs, but only twice.

It is the first time this has happened to me. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my phone and it worked again.

For anyone having similar problems, please do that. Don't be like me and remove all your current songs in your phone to no avail. You may even need to restart your PC, but I didn't have to.